# How to use center elements with flex-wrap without truncate them on very small windows width?

Tags: html, css

I have this piece of code on Codepen : [code](https://codepen.io/redanouar/pen/RwNBzWK)

Is there anyone who can help me trying to fix it ?
I try to center the elements like this :

[my centered elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vXKR.png)

and then, wrap the elements one below the other when the width of the window is reduced.

My first idea was to combine a flex-wrap, a justify-content and an align-content property, like this :

```
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
```

But the problem is that some elements are truncated when the windows width is very small :

[my truncated elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdZyW.png)

My question is :
how can I combine the centering of the elements and a flex-wrap without some elements being truncated ?

Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: Must the height of the container always be `350px`?

Comment: I would like, yes..

Answer (score 1):

You are manually setting the `height` to a max value. This is what's truncating your elements.

It's hard to tell exactly what you're going for, but it looks like changing `height: 350px;` to `min-height: 350px;` will still give you as much spacing as you want on desktop, but let it stretch to the right height on mobile.

**EDIT**
In order to keep a height of 350px, and if you're okay with having a flexible amount of space between the elements as they stack, change:

```
#container {
  align-content: center;
}
```

to

```
.element {
  align-self: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, I would like to keep my height fixed. This is precisely my problem ...
When I replace the value "center" of the align-content with "flex-start", I have what I want. But the problem is when I do that, my elements aren't vertically centered anymore when they aren't wrapped.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are trying to fit 450px of height into 350px of space, which just isn't possible. You'll need to decide what tradeoffs are acceptable for what you're trying to build.

Comment: It should be possible thanks to the scroll because it's possible when I set "flex-start" value to align-content property.

Comment: Sometimes the tools at hand limit us. When it comes to versatility in horizontal scrolling websites, you will find lots of limits to the tools you are using (CSS, HTML, JS, PHP Whatever else). This is because current trends are designed for web-sites not to scroll horizontally. In truth I see any website that scrolls HORIZONTALLY as a screwed up layout, and a poor experience to any users, especially mobile users, that visit the site.

Comment: In answer to your edit, the flexible amount of space between the elements bother me a lot because it's not the result I want. I would like my elements to be stuck together.

Comment: @ Aft3rL1f3 , in truth, i'm not doing this for a real project. It is simply a personal challenge. I tried to hack with flex displays and I came across this "limit". Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @RédaANOUAR If you truly are inflexible in changing what you're doing, then yes, you have come up against the limits of the spec.

Comment: @Caleb Anthony I find it unfortunate that there is no way to remove these spaces. If it had been possible, I would have combined your answer with the deletion of spaces and thus, my problem would have been solved. But as you have noticed, we are reaching the spec limits. Thank you a lot for your help.